# How can I reload a FragmentTab?

Tags: android

I have the following code to setup my fragment tabs.

```
mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Latest"), MainFragment.class,
                getBundle(0));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Today"), MainFragment.class,
                getBundle(1));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Week"), MainFragment.class,
                getBundle(2));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab4").setIndicator("Month"), MainFragment.class,
                getBundle(3));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab5").setIndicator("Year"), MainFragment.class,
                getBundle(4));
```

I need to programmatically load a tab when I click a button. I can setCurrentTab(1); setCurrentTab(0); to force reload but that's not a good way of doing it.

I can have a reload method inside my fragments to load the fragment. But I don't know how I can reference them since I only pass the class name to the tab host

Answer (score 0):

setCurrentTab() isn't so bad, it's a good way to change between tabs.
When a tab change, the listener OnTabChangeListener will be fired the same like the user click on other tab.

If you need to do a check or some intermediate task when click this button, you can do a intermediate method, but the final way to change the tab will be setCurrentTab().

On my projects, the onTabChangeListener do all smart part, so i don't have to worry about fragment stack.
If in your case you need to get the correct stack (back to another fragment), you can use "replace" on FragmentTransaction to maintain a correct stack.

Comment: Thanks for that but i am actually looking to for a way to reload a tab not to change it. changing it then changing it back will reload the tab but its a bad way because it will initiate the other tab which in my case will call the server and all sorts of things

Comment: aha, i misunderstood that part. Could you please explain why you want reload your activity but without changing your info and don't another server petition. Maybe i could help you more.